# How to Rig this specific Scarf?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, constraints, cloth-simulation

I dont know how to rig this specific scarf of this character. It needs the following features:

If the arm rotates (2_FK_ten_1.L ), the scarf controller (halstuch_02.L) should go up and also copy the rotation of the arm, so the arm doens't clip into the scarf. But the controller needs to be tweakable still.

[image]
[image]

I have made a setup so far - and the arm doesn't clip into the scarf - but the problem is, there is always a gap between arm and scarf and looks strange.

Addon "Bone Layer Manager" required. The Scarf controllers are in bonelayer "Scarf", the FK controllers are in "FK" and deformers are in "DEF" Bone Layer.

[image]

Comment: I might try setting up a little bones in the scarf that point downward, and then have drivers on them to basically copy the arm bone’s rotation, but only if it is greater than a certain value. Some brief subtraction inside a call to the max function that compares it with zero should do it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I tried the "Transform" constraint already - i also have set up the range, where this particular bone should move. Only issue here is, this works only for one rotation axis.

Is it actually possible to use multiple "Transform" constraints on one bone?

Comment: I don’t really know. I was actually talking about using python drivers in the individual rotation fields, and not using the ready-made bone constraints. I’m glad you’ve gotten this far without having to go in depth like I was suggesting.